# Add change event to element added after page load

Tags: jquery

I'm using ajax to add `#it_SelectCatLvl2` element in div `#div_it_SelectCatLvl2` and I see that when I change value `#it_SelectCatLvl2` the script doesn't work.

Code:

```
$('#it_SelectCatLvl2').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() > 0){
        $('#it_submit').removeAttr("disabled");
    }else{
        $('#it_submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});

<div id="div_it_SelectCatLvl2">
    <select class="n_SelectPath" style="" name="it_SelectCatLvl2" id="it_SelectCatLvl2">
        <option value="0">Change</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you please either show more code that includes what you are doing with the `.post()` or rewrite the question?

Comment: @iWizardPro sorry  i dont know how ask this, but i already get answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('#div_it_SelectCatLvl2').on('change', '#it_SelectCatLvl2', function() {
    $('#it_submit').prop('disabled', !(this.value > 0));
});
```

Your problem occurs because you're attaching the change event to an element which doesn't exist yet.

The code I've used is executed when a change event bubbles up to `#div_it_SelectCatLvl2` and has been triggered by an element with the id `#it_SelectCatLvl2`.